# How to track network traffic with Dart's webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy, dart, webdriver

The API doc is just too simple and I don't know how to  track of the network traffic with webdriver of dart, in selenuium one may can use something like:

```
   Proxy proxy = new Proxy(); 
    // The URL here is the URL that the browsermob proxy is using   
     proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:9100");     
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);   
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

But I am new to dart and don't know which library to use for setting up proxy and how to set proxy for dart webdriver.Can any one give me a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the driver like

```
WebDriver driver = await createDriver(
  uri: Uri.parse('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/'),
  desired: {'browserName': 'firefox', 
    'proxy': {'proxyType': 'direct', 'httpProxy': 'localhost:9100'}});
```

I haven't used proxy and don't know if `direct` makes sense here but some value is required. You can find possible values at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Proxy_JSON_Object